# sql query output get slower with ADODB.Recordset in VBA

Tags: vba, excel, ado

Please find my below VBA code.

```
Function SQL_query(ByRef sql_string As Variant)

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Dim cn As ADODB.Connection
Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset
Dim strSQL As String
Dim strCon As String


strFile = ThisWorkbook.FullName
strCon = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" & strFile _
& ";Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0;HDR=Yes;IMEX=1"";"

Set cn = New ADODB.Connection
Set rs1 = New ADODB.Recordset

cn.Open strCon

strSQL = sql_string

rs1.Open strSQL, cn, adOpenForwardOnly, adLockReadOnly
```

I am using below 2 method's to paste the data.

**1st Method:-**

```
    i = 2
    Do While Not rs1.EOF

            If rs1.Fields(0) <> "" Then
            Cells(i, 7) = rs1.Fields(0)
            End If
            rs1.MoveNext

  i = i + 1
  Loop
```

**2nd Method :-**

```
Sheet5.Range("G2").CopyFromRecordset rs1
```

Remaining Code

```
rs1.Close
cn.Close

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Function
```

With both the method its took 30-40 mints to paste 9,000 rows which is to much time consuming process. Please guide How can minimise the time.

Please find the SQL query string-

```
slt = "CStr([Sheet5$].[ClientCode])"

sql_string = "Select " & _
" CStr([one_key$].[APRIL 2017]) From [Sheet5$]" & _
 " LEFT JOIN [one_key$] On CStr([Sheet5$].[ClientCode]) = CStr(Mid([one_key$].[Client],InStr(1,[one_key$].[Client],""#"")+1))"
```

Comment: It shouldn't take 30+ minutes to paste only 9k records. Are you sure its the data paste that is taking so much time?

Comment: You can try to set Calculation to manual and disable events. Your 2nd method should bei fine then.

Comment: Have you tried with `Application.EnableEvents = False` and `Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual`?

Comment: @PankajJaju Sir, Please find my SQL query string which just now I have updated in question.. Yes Sir its taking this much time to paste...

Comment: have you step through code line-by-line to see which execution is slowest. At a glance all the code looks decent enough and should fly right through. (I suspect its the calcs though, so try turning off, as others have said).

Comment: If you remove `Cells(i, 7) = rs1.Fields(0)` from the first method how long does it take?

Comment: dear all experts, i have turn off both Calculation & Events but still it take 2-3 mints to just paste 1000 records, Please guide....

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid both the method take almost same long time to run...

Comment: @ScottHoltzman Yes i do checked step by step and the code is taking time on the mention methods only...

Comment: So if you're not interacting with excel and just stepping through the recordset then clearly it's the query. How many records are in the two sheets you are selecting from?

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid around 9k in **Sheet5** and 20k in **one_key** and 4 columns in  **Sheet5** and 8-9 columns in  **one_key**

Comment: Maybe the ACE driver just can't handle that volume of records with that kind of query.

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid Please guide how can i proceed further for the same...

Comment: Sorry my only advice is that you move it into a proper database. _or_ you could try pre-calculating the join keys and see if that helps - i.e. add a column that _already_ has `CStr([Sheet5$].[ClientCode])` and `CStr(Mid([one_key$].[Client],InStr(1,[one_key$].[Client],""#"")+1))` worked out in the sources and join directly on that - maybe it will help.

Comment: I gotta go to bed now but it might help if describe what you are trying to do - how often do you do this? how often does the data change? where does it come from?

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid its an daily activity data numbers is changing on daily basis, its come from from one of our portal where we do not have an access...

Comment: If the data changes daily why is 40 minutes processing time an issue? Are you reporting on this data? Just download Power BI which eats this stuff up

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid I checked with your above given solution ..but still taking the same time i am not geting y VBA excel is getting this much time to paste the data...

Comment: The problem isn't pasting. You took the 'Cells' bit out and it still took just as long. The problem is it can't handle your query. That's what I reckon anyway.

Comment: I would suggest trying a query without `Cstr` as your `IMEX` is already set to 1 and therefore query treats all data as text.

Comment: I'd time both parts of the code (i.e. the query and the pasting) to see where the bottleneck is. See the MSDN documentation [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/language-reference-vba/articles/timer-function).

Comment: Dear Experts,Thanks all for your suggestions, i change the format from text to Number in Excel data and i am now wiling to get the data in faster manner...